# Calculate cosine distance/similarity between 400K embeddings

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have a few lines of code where I have a `torch tensor` `(400.000 x 512)` and I want to calculate the **cosine distance/similarity** between each of those embeddings.

Right now, I'm doing:

```
similarity = features @ features.t()
```

Problems:

- Time that it takes
- Output is a `400.000 ** 2` matrix. That's huge.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the cosine similarity for each data?? Or do you just want to calculate the input with all data?

Comment: I want to see the distance's statistics.